# Are there any advantages of using a T2 over a T3 EC2 instance anymore?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In general I've seen that T3 (and now T4) instances on EC2 are both more cost-effective and powerful than T2 (obviously under the assumption it's the same type e.g medium).

The only exception I've seen for this is when using Windows AMIs it might be more cost-effective to use a T2. But looking specifically at AWS's on-demand pricing this doesn't appear to be true? https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

Is this actually true still? If so, what am I missing?

Comment: I think the free-tier pricing still only applies to T2. Otherwise it's almost always better to go with the newer instance types.

Comment: Older-gen instances are almost always worse value.

Comment: @Mark Yeah, they probably have a lot of unused T2 capacity, which they use for the Free Tier.

Comment: @MarkB This is from Amazon 'AWS Free Tier includes 750 hours of Linux and Windows t2.micro instances, ( t3.micro for the regions in which t2.micro is unavailable) each month for one year. To stay within the Free Tier, use only EC2 Micro instances.' - So would it only be applicable to use a T2 if you're making use of micros in regions with T2's available?

Comment: @GeorgetheDev that sounds correct.